# Not work search in active directory

Tags: java, ldap

I have a problem with novell.ldap. The connection is successful. I used the test server server http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server. In ldap browser successfully applied test mask "(cn=italians)". But not in my code.. What am I doing wrong ?

```
LdapConnection conn = new LdapConnection();
conn.Connect("ldap.forumsys.com", 389);
conn.Bind("cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com", "password");
LdapSearchResults searchResults_ = conn.Search("dc=example,dc=com", LdapConnection.SCOPE_SUB, "(cn=italians)", null, false);
conn.Disconnect();
```

[image]

Comment: Appears you are not enumerating your searchResults_. Try looking at: http://www.novell.com/documentation/developer/samplecode/jldap_sample/

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for `cn=italians` but the DIT has `ou=italians`.

Answer (score 0):

LdapSearchResult always return 0 items. Use .hasMore() / .next()